# How to return from a AWS Appsync resolver pipeline without throwing an error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, resolver, vtl

I have a resolver pipeline where I check to see if an item exists. If it does not I want to start a lambda which will create the data. If the queried item exists already I want to return from the pipeline altogether without executing the lambda. It seems AWS provides the following solutions:

```
#return
```

This only returns from the current request mapping template.

```
$util.error
```

This prevents subsequent functions from being executed by throwing an error immediately.

I want the functionality of `$util.error` without throwing an error but instead just returning the result from the current function. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to short-circuit the entire pipeline, while adding an error and specifying a result?

Comment: I just want to return from the current resolver with an early result, without executing subsequent resolver functions. Effectively an early return from the entire pipeline. I don't want to throw an error but just the functionality of an error, ending the pipeline.

Comment: I don't think such functionality actually exists, but perhaps you could write something to $context.stash, and subsequent functions in the pipeline could check for that and #return early or perform a no-op in the case of a Lambda function. I don't know if this would work in every situation, though, and it's not very elegant.

Comment: What I like about @MartinGressler's ask here is that it avoids having to manually override the auto-generated resolvers that Amplify gives you out of the box